# Background image shows zoomed in on iphone

Tags: html, css

i have some problems with the following code:

```html
<div id="home" class="parallax first-section wow fadeIn" style="background-image:url('images/slider-bg.png');">
```

On PC and Android, it shows to be working fine, but on iPhone (chrome and safari) it is extremely zoomed in.

The live Website: https://dentalcarea.000webhostapp.com
Thank you!

Comment: Hi there! Please also post the relevant CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to having the two meta tags with the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Leave it in only one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Or:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

but don't use the two or the `width=device-width` might not be set.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

`<div id="home" class="parallax first-section wow fadeIn" 
style="background:url('images/slider-bg.png')" background-size: cover;>`

I also modified meta in

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`
Thank you very much guys!!!